# Assigning a string with escaped characters to a property

Tags: string, powershell, shortcut-file

I want to set a string path to a string property of a `$Shortcut` object and it doesn't seam to work.

Running this code :

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell ;
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut('c:\aaa.lnk');
$Shortcut.TargetPath = '"c:\Program Files\MyApp.exe" /param1: (2) /param2 "val"'
```

I get this error while setting `$Shortcut.TargetPath`:

```
Exception setting "TargetPath": "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"
At line:1 char:11
+ $Shortcut. <<<< TargetPath = '"c:\Program Files\MyApp.exe" /param1: (2) /param2 "val"'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

The strange thing is that trying to reproduce this behavior on a new custom object, the problem doesn't appear. Just run the commands below:

```
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name prop -Value "aaa"
$object.prop = '"c:\Program Files\MyApp.exe" /param1: (2) /param2 "val"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The [`TargetPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property takes just the path to the excutable. The arguments go into the [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut('c:\aaa.lnk')
$Shortcut.TargetPath = 'c:\Program Files\MyApp.exe'
$Shortcut.Arguments  = '/param1: (2) /param2 "val"'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out . I'll have to watch out for that one .I used a normal link item in windows with params in the target and copied those from the properties view GUI into the string TargetPath string.